# Adding a new nonlinear function to another nonlinear function would improve the nonlinearity?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, convolution, nonlinear-system, neural-networks

Assume we have a combination of different functions as below:
[image]

X is the input and it is a 2D matrix.

$f(X)$ is a linear operation.

$g(Y)=max(0,Y)$ is a nonlinear operation.

$k(Z)$ is a linear operation.

$h(Y)$ is a nonlinear operation that is more complex than $g(Y)$.

Now the relationship between A and the input vector X can be defined:
$$A=\Gamma(X)$$
Where $\Gamma(X)$ can include or exclude the $h(Y)$.

Including $h(Y)$ gives us:
$$\Gamma_a(X)=f(X)\circ g(Y)\circ k(Z)+h(Y)$$

And excluding $h(Y)$ yields:

$$\Gamma_b(X)=f(X)\circ g(Y)\circ k(Z)$$

Is it possible to prove mathematically that adding a more complex nonlinear function, $h(Y)$, to the system can enhance the overall nonlinearity when a nonlinear function $g(Y)$ is already present? In other words, the nonlineariy provided by $\Gamma_a(X)$ is better than $\Gamma_b(X)$?

**Some Details**: I am looking for a general proof. The question is in the context of neural network. $g$ is a [ReLU activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) and $h$ is a [morphological operation (like erosion)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)). The goal in neural network is to fit a nonlinear function between input and output. I need to generally prove that adding h in addition to $g$ improves then nonlinearity than having the $g$ solely. I though that by approximating erosion to have it as a continuous function and then by taking second derivative, we might prove that the network includes more nonlinearity. But I am not sure if this approach is correct.

Comment: How do you measure "overall nonlinearity" and when is one function's nonlinearity "better" than another's? And when you say "can enhance" rather than "will enhance", does that mean you merely need one example of functions $f,g,k,h$ for which $\Gamma_a$ is better than $\Gamma_b$, or are you looking for something more general?

Comment: @DavidK, I am looking for a general proof. The question is in the context of neural network. $g$ is a ReLU activation function and $h$ is a morphological operation (like erosion). The goal in neural network is to fit a nonlinear function between input and output. I need to generally prove that adding $h$ in addition to $g$ improves then nonlinearity than having the $g$ solely. I though that by approximating erosion to have it as a continuous function and then by taking second derivative, we might prove that the network includes more nonlinearity. But I am not sure if this approach is correct.

Comment: Those details are all essential to understanding the question and should be **edited** into the main part of the question itself. And then you have to hope that someone is familiar enough with neural networks to give an insight.